# RedirectToAction Return URL Formatting Long-winded/incorrectly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Why in ASP.NET MVC is it when I use a:

```
return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Page", new { pageKey = "test/ho/hum"})
```

or using the MVCContrib extension:

```
return this.RedirectToAction<PageController>(c => c.Index("test/ho/hum"))
```

formats my return URL as:
`http://localhost:8882/?pageKey=test%2Fho%2Fhum`
and not:
`http://localhost:8882/test/ho/hum`

The latter is the usual way my route is accessible, the querystring'd approach functions but reveals pageKey and is not desirable.  FYI I have a catch-all route setup as `{*pageKey}` pointing to Index() on PageController.

Any ideas why `RedirectToAction` would format like that?

Comment: you'll need to include your routes for anyone to debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Global.asax.cs file, try to add the following routing info:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            "my customized routing",
            "Index/Page/{*MyPageKey}",
            new { controller = "Index", Action = "List", MyPageKey= "" }
        );
```

you may be able to get what you expect. However, this might create a host of bugs in your application. So used with caution.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Routing goes through the list of routes and finds the first one that matches. In this case ther emust be an earlier route before your {*pageKey} route that is matching.

Try using `RedirectToRoute`, where you can specify the route's name to ensure that only that route can match.